# Set value in web property bag using REST API

Tags: 2013, web-services, rest, web, property-bag

I am trying to manage web properties from property bag using REST API.

It is pretty straightforward how to get the values

```
var url = "https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/allProperties";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

However, I am unable to set the specific property. Any ideas how to achieve that?

What I have found at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn499819.aspx), the AllProperties is available only for read in REST

Comment: I also could not find any example using REST api to set property bag. If JSOM is an option, you can try that to set the property bag value. http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2011/10/03/making-use-of-the-property-bag-in-the-ecmascript-client-object-model/

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use Script Editor Web Part so afaik client context will not be available. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Client context will be available. Wrap the call in `SP.SOD.executeFunc`. Do you want me to share the code with you?

Comment: Ah, you are right. Thanks for pointing this out! However, still curious about the REST approach.

Comment: I am also curious. If there is any way of doing it, I am sure @Vadim will have the answer. He may be crafting one for you right now. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/10610/vadim-gremyachev