# Looping through document libraries

Tags: document-library

What is the best way to loop through all the document libraries in a web application using REST API.

I need to find the particular document based on the ID in a whole web application. I don't want to loop through all the document libraries one by one. is there any better way to achieve this using REST?

Comment: You are not aware in which document library this document is?

Comment: No.it can be in any document library

Comment: ID is the normal IDs like 1,2,3 or its generated via Doc ID service?

Comment: its generated via Doc ID service

Answer (score 2):

IDs of documents generated by Doc ID service is something like `N3SITE-424387581-13`.

If we try to break the Id `N3SITE-424387581-13` we can notice that

1. N3SITE: is the prefix which we have in Document ID settings.
2. 424387581: Is the random number generated by SharePoint.
3. 13: is nothing but the normal ID of a document.

N3SITE and 13 are quite easy to understand and they are in our control to identify which site collection. But 424387581 puzzle us, and also from site collection which library it belongs we would also like to know that.

`424387581` is nothing but the unique Id given to a document library. but from where we got to know it?

**Cracking down curious case of 424387581**: Open your office 365 site collection in SharePoint Designer. From ribbon control click on Site Options which is a property bag. Find the property `docid_msft_hier_listidx`, this contains the unique id for all the document libraries.

Refer [find source of a record in record centre using Document ID service](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/sharepoint-2013-office365-find-source-of-a-record-in-record-centre-using-document-id-service/)

**How to that in REST**: As you have mentioned in comments, that you have the Document ID. You can follow below steps

1. Extract out the middle part of the ID, i.e. `424387581`
2. Find out how to use REST to query the property bag and get value of `key=424387581`. Refer [value in web property bag using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133924/set-value-in-web-property-bag-using-rest-api)
3. From step 2 you will get the GUID of the document library.
4. Query the document library with the ID(the last part of Doc ID). And thats it.

Comment: Do you know how to query property bag to get value of key?

Comment: No never done that. But get all the properties, I think it will be in xml format then query xml.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer. i will try this out and let you know